# problem with D-Link DUB-E100 usb to ethernet adapter

Tags: 12.04, drivers, usb, ethernet, adapter

I am trying to use a D-Link DUB-E100 usb to Ethernet adapter. It uses the ASIX 8817X chipset. I have Ubuntu 12.04 kernel 3.2.0-39. The driver supplied with the adapter did not compile. I downloaded an ASIX driver ver 4.6.0. It compiled and I loaded the module. The lsusb command rerurns the following:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0158 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 2.0 multicard reader
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 2001:1a02 D-Link Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 13ba:0017 Unknown PS/2 Keyboard+Mouse Adapter
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 046d:c52a Logitech, Inc.
```

Ifconfig does not report the adapter.

lshw -C network does not report the adapter.

Please help.

Bob

Comment: ...and the problem is...? How did the 4.6.0 Asix deriver work for you? What happened after loading the module?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need it but I had the same problem with kernel 3.2.30. I recompiled the asix drivers 4.6.0 and loaded the modules asix, usbnet and cdc_ether and it works perfectly.